# Vertical scroll in sub-menu not working

Tags: css, mobile, scroll

I have an issue.
I have menu navigation on site and also submenu (drop-down). If I open my site on mobile device, then open main menu and click on submenu, then I am not able to scroll down, to see my all sub-menus items , although I see that scroll is moving, but nothing happens

My css code:

```css
.mobile-nav .smr-res-nav li {
  margin: 5px 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.mobile-nav .smr-res-nav li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.site-navigation-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;

}
.main-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.main-navigation > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}
.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
}
.main-navigation li:after {
  content: "";
  background: #ff5050;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
}
.main-navigation .smr-main-nav > .current-menu-item:after,
.main-navigation .smr-main-nav > li:hover:after,
.main-navigation .smr-main-nav ul > li:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
.main-navigation a {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #484848 !important;
  
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}
.main-navigation ul ul {
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 103%;
  left: -999em;
  z-index: 99999;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
 transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0.795, 0, 1);
}
.main-navigation ul ul li {
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
}
.main-navigation ul ul ul {
  left: -999em;
  top: 0;
}
.main-navigation ul ul a {
  width: 200px;
}
.main-navigation ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul li.focus > ul {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}
.main-navigation ul ul li:hover > ul,
.main-navigation ul ul li.focus > ul {
  left: 100%;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu li:first-child a {
  padding: 10px 0 5px;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu li:last-child a {
  padding: 5px 0 10px;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu a {
  padding: 5px 0 5px;
}
.main-navigation .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f107";
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.main-navigation .sub-menu .menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f105";
  margin-right: 20px;
  float: right;
     }
```

```html
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
  <ul id="smr-main-nav" class="smr-main-nav">
    <li id="menu-
    item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page 
    menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-2 current_page_item 
    menu-item-21"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-22"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-23"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-24"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-25" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-25"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-247" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-247"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-207" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-
    object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-207"><a href="#">MAINMENU</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-176" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-176"><a href="#">SUBMENU</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-195" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-195"><a href="#">SUBMENU</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-198" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-198"><a href="#">SUBMENU</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-165" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-165"><a href="#">SUBMENU</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-313" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-
    object-page menu-item-313"><a href="#">SUBMENU</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: could you post some html code aswell? or make a fiddle at https://www.jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Yes, sure. Added to my first post

Comment: not enough css.. please add more

Comment: There are a lot of css code. Code of what tags should I add?

Comment: the relevant ones! ones used in the nav bar.. the ones you have posted in the html

Comment: i mean add the css style! the css styling code for the tags used

Comment: Added again the code for menu navigation. Could you please check?

Comment: your submenus are displaying and highlighting as i move down the options.. what exactly is the problem? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: if your submenus are not visible when the rest of the content/html is present, then you may just need to add a z-index to your css for the nav bar. set it to 1 .. that should work..

Answer (score 0):

try adding `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

We set the overflow-scroll type of touching to allow for momentum scrolling in mobile devices. Explained in a bit more detail below:

Setting auto will work on some devices, but set this to scroll just to be sure.
This the magic property that enables the native feel scrolling.
Setting this to justify creates equally spaced li’s which takes the headache of working out margins.
You must set the width to a value larger than the sum of all the li’s width.